# Obtaining UK Residence Permit

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I am a citizen of Mauritius married to the UK citizen and I have a child with him.  According to UK immigration law, to be abe to sponsor his family for residence he needs to earn £18,300 per year, but his salary do not meet the amount, as he just started working.

My baby an I are still in Mauritius. I want to know if it will be possible for us to stay with him in UK if the got his place as he is actually living at his uncle's at the moment.

What are the formalities to get a resident permit for my baby and i?

Comment: Is there a chance he could go and work elsewhere in the EU for 6-12 months? That'd mean taking the [Surinder Singh route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surinder_Singh_route), with you all living elsewhere in the EU.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow the directions as laid out in [Applying to join family living permanently in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/exceptions).

You may also need to check whether or not your child is a [British Citizen](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen) and then meet the financial requirements, which quite possibly may be not £18600 but £22400 per year.

That said there is an application you can fill out online to join your family in the UK as linked on the [Applying to join family living permanently in UK](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/exceptions), which you can fill out and then follow the rest of instructions provided.